# What's the difference between adding PRIMARY KEY constraint on table level and on column level?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

As the question title described, we can add `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on column level:

```sql
animals=# CREATE TABLE temp (
id serial UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE
animals=# \d temp
                            Table "public.temp"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('temp_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "temp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**Or on table level:**

```sql
animals=# CREATE TABLE temp_1 (
id serial UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE
animals=# \d temp_1
                            Table "public.temp_1"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('temp_1_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "temp_1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

---

- Is there any noticeable difference between these two methods to add `PRIMARY KEY` constraint(or other constraints)?
- Would this affect how tables reference each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all.
The name itself, **PRIMARY** KEY suggests it is not something defined on a single column level.

What you call "on column level" is in fact nothing more than a convenience syntax for when the primary key consists in a single column.

BTW, Primary key means `NOT NULL UNIQUE`, so you can skip defining them as `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2):

- Both primary key and unique key are entity integrity constraints that are similar in many aspects. However, they have their fair share of differences when it comes to programming. Both are essential concepts that are primarily used in database management systems.
- Primary key is a set of one or more columns/fields of a database table that uniquely identify a record in a table. Unique key, on the other hand, prevents two records from having identical values in a column.
- Conceptually, there can only be one PRIMARY KEY for a given table, while there can be more than one UNIQUE KEY for a table.
- A primary key must be unique but a unique key does not necessarily have to be the primary key.
- A primary key cannot accept NULL values in a table, whereas a unique key can allow NULL values with an exception of only one NULL in a table.

You can refer the article on : http://covelign.com/3Y8P